# How can we set CORS for folders in Amazon S3 Buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I've set permission on Bucket and CORS header is set on any file in root of the bucket but not for files inside a folder in Bucket. Is there a way to set CORS on files inside folder as well?

Answer (score 7):

If you have configured CORS on a bucket, then that configuration is active for *all* files in the bucket.  S3 had no other options for CORS.  If it appears that files outside the root don't have CORS active, you are almost certainly seeing cached responses, coming from somewhere other than S3 (which does not cache anything, itself).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it might help. The CORS might come from Cloudfront because of the cached response.
To remove the cached files from a Cloudfront distribution you can do so going directly to the CloudFront distribution in the AWS Cli -> Invalidations and create an invalidation with `/*`. This will removed all the cached objects from the root